# xslt to skip already "visited" nodes

Tags: xslt

not sure if this is possible without having to go through several passes, but I'll ask anyway (my XSL is a little rusty)

I have an XML document, which contains nodes as follows:

```
<structures>
 <structure id="STRUCT_A">
   <field idref="STRUCT_B" name="b"/>
   <field idref="STRUCT_C" name="c"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_D" name="d"/>
 </structure>

 <structure id="STRUCT_B">
   <field idref="STRUCT_C" name="c"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_E" name="e"/>
 </structure>

 <structure id="STRUCT_C">
   <field idref="FIELD_E" name="e"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_F" name="f"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_G" name="g"/>
 </structure>
</structures>
```

(The real file contains lots of structure tags which interdependencies, none of which are circular!)

What I want to do is to generate some text (in this case C++ `struct`s), and the obvious requirement is the order of the `struct`s, so my ideal output would be

```
struct STRUCT_C
{
  FIELD_E e;
  FIELD_F f;
  FIELD_G g;
};

struct STRUCT_B
{
  STRUCT_C c;
  FIELD_E e;
};

struct STRUCT_A
{
  STRUCT_B b;
  STRUCT_C c;
  FIELD_D d;
};
```

I know I could use forward declarations and that would mean that the order doesn't matter, however the problem is that there will be "processing" code inline in the structures, and they  would require the real definition to be present.

So far I can detect to see if a `structure` has any dependencies, with the following bit of xsl:

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant::*/@idref">
  <xsl:variable name="name" select="."/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="//structure[@id = $name]" mode="struct.dep"/> 
</xsl:for-each>
```

(this happens inside a `<xsl:template match="structure">`)

Now, theoretically, I could then follow this dependency "chain" and generate the `struct`s for each entry first, then the one that I am currently at, however as you can imagine, this generates lot's of copies of the same structure - which is a pain..

Is there anyway to avoid the copies? Basically, once a structure has been visited, and if we visit again, not to bother outputting the code for it... I don't need the full xslt to do this (unless it's trivial!), but just any ideas on approaches...

If there isn't, I could in theory wrap the `struct` with a `#ifdef`/`#define`/`#endif` guard so that the compiler only uses the first definition, however this is REALLY NASTY! :(

(NOTES: xslt 1.0, xsltproc on linux: Using libxml 20623, libxslt 10115 and libexslt 812)

Comment: Excellent question, +1. See my answer for a complete and short solution. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vLeafs" select="/*/structure[not(field/@idref = /*/structure/@id)]"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vLeafs[1]">
   <xsl:with-param name="pVisited" select="'|'"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="structure">
   <xsl:param name="pVisited"/>

struct <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
{<xsl:text/>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
};
  <xsl:variable name="vnewVisited"
       select="concat($pVisited, @id, '|')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select=
  "../structure[not(contains($vnewVisited, concat('|', @id, '|')))
              and
                not(field/@idref
                           [not(contains($vnewVisited, concat('|', ., '|')) )
                          and
                           . = ../../../structure/@id
                           ]
                   )
               ] [1]
  ">
   <xsl:with-param name="pVisited" select="$vnewVisited"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#xA;   ', @idref, ' ', @name, ';')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<structures>
 <structure id="STRUCT_A">
   <field idref="STRUCT_B" name="b"/>
   <field idref="STRUCT_C" name="c"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_D" name="d"/>
 </structure>

 <structure id="STRUCT_B">
   <field idref="STRUCT_C" name="c"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_E" name="e"/>
 </structure>

 <structure id="STRUCT_C">
   <field idref="FIELD_E" name="e"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_F" name="f"/>
   <field idref="FIELD_G" name="g"/>
 </structure>
</structures>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
struct STRUCT_C
{
   FIELD_E e;
   FIELD_F f;
   FIELD_G g;
};


struct STRUCT_B
{
   STRUCT_C c;
   FIELD_E e;
};


struct STRUCT_A
{
   STRUCT_B b;
   STRUCT_C c;
   FIELD_D d;
};
```

**Explanation**:
`structure` elements are processed strictly one by one. At any time we process the first `structure` element whose `id` isn't yet registered in the `pVisited` parameter and that has no `field/@idref` value that isn't already in the `pVisited` parameter and refers to an existing `structure` element.

Comment: +1 good approach: process from the leaves up, so that you don't have to modify and pass as much state information. I'm still digesting your answer...

Comment: +1, works for me, now need to map it to the real xml document I have, that'll be fun! Thanks v. much gents!

Comment: @LarsH: This is not from the leaves, but from the root.

Comment: @Alej: what I mean is that in the "/*" template, @Dimitre applies templates only to the first leaf structure, i.e. structure that has no dependencies. The "structure" template then recurses on structures that have no *unmet* dependencies once the current structure has been defined. Thus he is working from the leaves to the roots, if you consider the structures as a "grove" where the "child" relationship models a struct dependency relationship.

Comment: @LarsH: Yes, your understanding is correct. @Alejandro meant the formal structure of the XML document, but here the logical structure imposed by the dependencies is more important.

Comment: I meant that this takes one root (no dependencies) and search no visited with no other dependencies than already visited, in other words, direct descendant or other root.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, other approach (level by level) and ussing keys:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:key name="kStructById" match="structure" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:key name="kStructByIdref" match="structure" use="field/@idref"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:param name="pParents" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:param name="pChilds"
                   select="structures/structure[not(key('kStructById',
                                                        field/@idref))]"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vParents" select="$pParents|$pChilds"/>
        <xsl:variable name="vChilds"
                      select="key('kStructByIdref',$pChilds/@id)
                                 [count(key('kStructById',
                                             field/@idref) |
                                        $vParents) =
                                  count($vParents)]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$pChilds"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[$vChilds]">
            <xsl:with-param name="pParents" select="$vParents"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="pChilds" select="$vChilds"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="structure">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('struct ',@id,'&#xA;{&#xA;')"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>};&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#x9;',@idref,' ',@name,';&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
struct STRUCT_C
{
    FIELD_E e;
    FIELD_F f;
    FIELD_G g;
};
struct STRUCT_B
{
    STRUCT_C c;
    FIELD_E e;
};
struct STRUCT_A
{
    STRUCT_B b;
    STRUCT_C c;
    FIELD_D d;
};
```

Comment: Nice. I'm not sure I've ever seen a "/" template apply templates to "/" recursively. :-)

Comment: @LarsH: Ja! That is the same as ussing template references. But in this case is just an esoteric form to avoid one `xsl:if`...

Answer (score 2):

Ooh, this is more complicated than it looked at first. +1 for good question.

I think the best way to accomplish this in XSLT 1.0 would be to pass an accumulating parameter whenever you apply-templates to a structure. The parameter (call it "$visited-structures") is a space-delimited list of names of structures you've already processed.

**Update: finally got this. :-)**

In the template for processing a structure, check whether any other structures this one depends on are not already listed in $visited-structures. If not, generate the code for this structure, and recurse on the template selecting the next non-visited structure, appending the current structure name to the $visited-structures parameter. Otherwise, don't generate code for the structure but recurse on the template selecting the first dependency structure, passing the $visited-structures parameter unmodified.

Here is the code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   version="1.0">
   <xsl:key name="structuresById" match="/*/structure" use="@id" />

   <xsl:template match="structures">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="structure[1]" >
         <!-- a space-delimited list of id's of structures already processed, with space
            at beginning and end. Could contain duplicates. -->
         <xsl:with-param name="visited-structures" select="' '"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="structure">
      <xsl:param name="visited-structures" select="' '" />  
      <xsl:variable name="dependencies" select="key('structuresById', field/@idref)
                     [not(contains($visited-structures, @id))]"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$dependencies">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$dependencies[1]">
               <xsl:with-param name="visited-structures" select="$visited-structures"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>            
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Now generate code for this structure ... ... -->
struct <xsl:value-of select="@id"/>
{
<xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>};
            <xsl:variable name="new-visited" select="concat(' ', @id, $visited-structures)"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/structure[not(contains($new-visited, @id))][1]" >
               <xsl:with-param name="visited-structures" select="$new-visited"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>      
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="field">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('  ', @idref, ' ', @name, ';&#xa;')"/>      
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

struct STRUCT_C
{
  FIELD_E e;
  FIELD_F f;
  FIELD_G g;
};


struct STRUCT_B
{
  STRUCT_C c;
  FIELD_E e;
};


struct STRUCT_A
{
  STRUCT_B b;
  STRUCT_C c;
  FIELD_D d;
};
```

Comment: P.S. You also have to pass an additional parameter to the template for `<structure>`, telling it whether or not to recurse on the following sibling. This would only be true at the top level, i.e. when applied in the template for processing `<structures>`.

Comment: variable that's passed sounds like an idea, however will there not be a scope problem? i.e. each root `structure` node is called with a blank `$visited-structures`? Hence there will still be multiple copies of the structure nodes?

Comment: Wow, it looks like you even have to pass around a "continuation"! Or at least a list of structures yet to process.

Comment: @Nim, the template for `structures` only applies templates to the *first* `structure` child (and passes a blank $visited-structures). That template then passes its expanded $visited-structures when applying templates to its following-sibling. etc.

Comment: @LarsH, I've accepted @Dimitre's answer as it does what I need, thank you for your effort though!

Comment: @Nim: understood... I'm going to keep working on my solution though, just so I can say I finished it. :-)

Comment: @Dimitre, @Alejandro, just wanted to let you know that I finished my solution. :-) I'm not going to try to polish and optimize it, but this is one I felt like I at least needed to get it working. Turned out I didn't need to pass all that stuff around after all, since the list of structures that need to be generated is always available.