# Adding graph edges/references using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

my problem is the following: In a structure containing nodes and edges I want to add edges in order to visit all nodes. An input could be some
thing like:

```
<graph>
    <item id="1" type="entry">
    </item>
    <item id="2" type="incoming">
    </item>
    <item id="3" type="incoming">
    </item>
    <item id="4" type="body">
        <connection>6</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="5" type="declaration"></item>
    <item id="6" type="contents">
        <connection>7</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="7" type="contents">
        <connection>8</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="8" type="contents"></item>
</graph>
```

As you can see there would not be a complete "connection"-path over all elements. The path should be completed by visiting (in given order) all
 @type='incoming', all @type='declaration' and finaly @type='body' leaving all other connections as they are. Like:

```
<graph>
    <item id="1" type="entry">
        <connection>2</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="2" type="incoming">
        <connection>3</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="3" type="incoming">
        <connection>5</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="4" type="body">
        <connection>6</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="5" type="declaration">
        <connection>4</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="6" type="contents">
        <connection>7</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="7" type="contents">
        <connection>8</connection>
    </item>
    <item id="8" type="contents"></item>
</graph>
```

I don't know how to achieve that as I wold have to "remember" which nodes I've visited. Is something like that possible using XSLT-2.0?
Thanks for your help!

p.s. the items are not necessarily sorted by id as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Remembering" which nodes have already been visited is done by using recursive template calls, and passing a parameter that accumulates a nodeset (or sequence) of already-visited nodes. XSLT 2.0 makes this easier, using sequences and set operations, but XSLT 1.0 can do it fine.

See [xslt to skip already "visited" nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205865/xslt-to-skip-already-visited-nodes) for example implementations.

Comment: That's a great approach! Thank you :)